# Installed Fedora 18 on UEFI machine, got lvm.mod not found error

Tags: fedora, grub2, uefi

I've installed Fedora 18 on UEFI system, when I boot the computer I get this error message:

```
File "/EFI/fedora/x86_64-efi/lvm.mod" not found
no server specified
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug (#906203). Apparently, as suggested in the bug report (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=906203), doing the following should work:

```
cp /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi/*.mod /boot/efi/fedora/x86_64-efi
```

You can use a live environment for this combined with chroot. On the other hand, if you have no special need for LVM, use plain old partitions and it should just work (TM).

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try it, but could you tell me what is LVM and how to use plain old partitions as you say ?

Comment: LVM is logical volume manager. It's a layer that sits on top of physical drives so you can bundle them into groups and present them as a single entity. When you do the install, go through and select a custom partitioning scheme and just partition the drive up as desired without LVM.

Comment: Note the bug says this only happens with `/boot` on LVM, and that that's not officially supported.  If `/boot` was a regular partition it would have been fine... if the automatic partitioning scheme put `/boot` on LVM that sounds like a (different!) bug.